# dyadic maximum in matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Imagine you have the matrix `mat`:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,2,3,3,0,1,1,1,0), nrow = 3,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(mat) <- list("a","b","c")
colnames(mat) <- list("a","b","c")
mat
#  a b c
#a 0 2 3
#b 3 0 1
#c 1 1 0
```

I want to find the which of the upper and lower triangle pairs are the biggest. e.g. `b:a` is `>`than `a:b` and `a:c` is `>`than `c:a`.

I then want to return a mtrix where the cell with the biggest value in the pair gets a 1 and evrything else, smaller values and ties get a zero. The result for `mat` would be:

```
result <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), nrow = 3,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(result ) <- list("a","b","c")
colnames(result ) <- list("a","b","c")
result
# a b c
#a 0 0 1
#b 1 0 0
#c 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
> (mat > t(mat)) + 0
  a b c
a 0 0 1
b 1 0 0
c 0 0 0
```

To return 0.5 for ties:

```
> (mat > t(mat)) + .5 * (mat == t(mat))
    a   b   c
a 0.5 0.0 1.0
b 1.0 0.5 0.5
c 0.0 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: +1 could this be modified so that ties both  get 0.5 ?